# You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory

Tags: ios, macos, flurry

when I tried to integrate flurry analysis into my ios app, I followed the instruction online. However, after I did the step shown below, I faced an error shown below. I've searched solution online but there is no one that exactly solves my puzzle. Could anyone help me solve this problem? Appreciate it!

---

sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

### You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need root privilege to write into /usr/bin

```
sh-4.2$ ls -ld /usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root 36864 Mar 20 18:40 /usr/bin
```

Comment: On recent versions of macOS, the /usr/bin directory is protected even from root by [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really). Local installs really belong in /usr/local (in this case, /usr/local/bin) anyway; macOS just enforces this now.